# can't place call from webpage in android app

Tags: android, permissions

I have an app that points the user to a webpage with a phone number in it. But when trying to call from the phone number I get an error message.

For the Android manifest, I tried to request phone permissions with both

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

and

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"></uses-feature>
```

Neither work.

The error message I get is `The web page at tel:(the phone number) might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address`.

So what am I missing here?

Comment: Can you please post the code you're using to retrieve the telephone number and the code you're using to initiate the telephone call?

Comment: From any webpage on an android device, you're supposed to be able to just tap the phone number to initiate the call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that the *html* link for the phone number is something along the lines of:

```
<a href="tel:+18001234567">Call us now!</a>
```